RAG is generating random letters and numbers
Currently using LLamaindex to make a RAG, implemented, Phi-3-4k-mini-instruct-q4.gguf. For some reason it worked once, but after that one time, it will generate utter BS,  Output below.
Siren\n
Information Retrieval:231.pdf
Siren’s research paper.pdf
Siren’s\\16459789999
Search Engineer’s999 (BotG01099. Theories. 
 Preview
10 Internal Credentials\3201: Siren\10
11: ASSearch11, Information: Natural:11111101110111017P1111111191111518
1.11.1.1s.\31.1010, 
1.11. Theories. Discussed:1010101.101 and1:1.10101
1.
1.1219101
1.1.10. Identifying.\345:01:1001,
1.
:112

Not sure if it's how I set up the LLM or what's causing it, cause it did work once perfectly. Below are details :
llm = LlamaCPP(
    model_path="model\Phi-3-mini-4k-instruct-q4.gguf",
    temperature=0.1,
    max_new_tokens=512,
    context_window=4096,
    generate_kwargs={"stop":['<|endoftext|>']},
    model_kwargs={"n_gpu_layers": -1},  # if compiled to use GPU
    verbose=True,
)

embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbedding(
    model_name="Snowflake/snowflake-arctic-embed-s"
)
Settings.embed_model = embed_model

query_engine = index.as_query_engine(streaming=True,similarity_top_k=5)

qa_prompt_template_str = """<|user|>Context information is below.
---------------------
{context_str}
---------------------
Given the context information and not prior knowledge, answer the query. 
Query: {query_str}
<|end|>
<|assistant|>
"""

qa_prompt_template = PromptTemplate(qa_prompt_template_str)
query_engine.update_prompts(
    {"response_synthesizer:text_qa_template":qa_prompt_template}
)

I have tried to change context window, stop words, but I am unable to repeat the performance of the RAG the first time it worked. After that, it never worked again,(generating random words and numbers) despite not changing anything.
